# perform alert when seperate function is done using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have one function in page. I want to perform alert when changecolor() complete action. But the problem is I cannot change in changecolor() due to some restriction. So is there anyway to know that function is done. I have attached demo [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FbT9/2/)

```
function changecolor(id){
$(id).css('backgroundColor','green')

}
changecolor().done(function(){
alert(0)
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trigger one function after done with another function you could use [when/then](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/). Also in your original fiddle you are not passing a parameter to the changecolor() function

```
function changecolor(id){

$.when($(id).css('backgroundColor','green')).then(alert('0'));

}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3FbT9/7/)

Comment: Thank one more think. I the text changing in div instead of color then how to do it

Comment: I notice that u are using $.when inside the changecolor function, But i cannot do that because of some restriction here

Comment: As for text change, what needs to be changed? have you added jQuery reference?

Comment: Not clear on what you are trying to achieve. You could write couple of functions and in the when part define what needs to be done first & in then part specifying the follow up function. http://jsfiddle.net/3FbT9/9/

Answer (score 0):

Ok try this

```
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#000" onclick="changecolor(this); alert(0);"></div>
```

Or wrap both functions in a single method

Comment: Please attached fiddle. changecolor function get call on click

Comment: I cannot change into html. My requirement is when u click on div it turn green then my function should call.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend you can do like this...

```
function changecolor(id){
$(id).css('backgroundColor','green')

}
function CallChangeColor(id){
        changecolor(id);
    alert(0);
}
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#000" onclick="CallChangeColor(this);"></div>
```

or you can do something like this...

```
function changecolor(id){
$(id).css('backgroundColor','green')

}
<div style="width:200px; height:200px; background:#000" onclick="changecolor(this);alert(0);"></div>
```